# Can I use a basic ADSL modem with modem+router?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, modem, adsl

I have a TP-LINK TD W8951ND wireless Modem+Router which contains one RJ11 (phone line) port and four RJ45 (Ethernet) ports along with wireless N support.

Now for some reason, my TP-LINK modem doesn't work with my ISP, whereas the modem provided by my ISP works. If I wish I could get the basic modem provided by my ISP which contains one RJ11 port and one Ethernet port.

So can I link both the modems?
I mean will this configuration work:
Connect telephone cable to basic modem provided by ISP.
And then connect the Ethernet port of basic modem to the Ethernet port of TP-link modem.
And then connect remaining Ethernet ports to PC and laptop and simultaneously use WIFI.

Will it work or should I have to replace my TP-Link Modem+Router?

Comment: What do you mean doesnt work with isp ? try to upgrade the firmware.. these are network protocols, PPPoE etc.. else the modem might be damaged

Comment: It should work, but as @ilansch mentioned, you should get around to figuring out why the TP link doesn't work. My bet is on incorrect PPPoE username / wrong Port/VPI/VCI values if yiu're on a ADSL network

Comment: Try cloning the MAC address of the ISP's ADSL modem to the TP-Link. You should be able to simply type the numbers in using the web interface.  This would be on the "Interface Setup" / "Internet" page, "MAC spoofing".

Comment: Now i sorted it all. There was a problem in the exchange with my phone line. They changed the port and it got working. And i replaced the modem as well. But the old one will have worked well. I'm happy that it is solved despite i replaced the modem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are doing should work - you are effectively turning the TP-Link device into a switch + AP.   I have done something a bit similar at home (but different hardware).

Comment: Thanks. As my problem was solved now, i need not do that. Will think of it when needed.